# How to load in Python load csv file that has a column with an array in it

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv

Using python how can I load a csv file that one of the columns is an array.

so if I have a csv file like such

```
time,account,status,values
0912,srvA,disabled,[['removed', 'admin'], ['added','disabled', '0x9923'], ['filler', 'filler', 'filler']
```

when I read in the csv file. the column values is read in as a single string. rather than an array of arrays.

how can I can I read in this file so that values may be accessed like such.

```
with open(fileName[0], 'r') as reader :
                importReader = csv.reader(reader);
                for line in importReader:
                    if line[0] != "time" and line[1] != "account" and line[2] != "status":
                        print(line[4][0])
```

should print

```
['removed', 'admin']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "values" column is formatted properly as an actual list and being read in as a string you can use `eval()` to convert it to a list:

```
>>> list_as_string = '[["removed", "admin"], ["added","disabled", "0x9923"], ["filler", "filler", "filler"]]'
>>> type(list_as_string)
<type 'str'>
>>> list_as_list = eval(list_as_string)
>>> type(list_as_list)
<type 'list'>
```

So to fix your example:

```
with open(fileName[0], 'r') as reader :
    importReader = csv.reader(reader)
    for line in importReader:
        print(eval(line[4])[0])
```

would print the first sublist within the evaluated list in the "values" column in each read line

Comment: Oh I wish I had seen this before I changed all my code. If I can't get my code working I may have to go with this.

Comment: If this answer is correct, you could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files don't support lists like that, so strictly speaking that might not be a CSV file. You could put square brackets around the line, and import it as JSON. That might work.

```
import json

line = '[' + line + ']'
mylist = json.loads(line)
print(mylist[3][0])
```

You would also need to put another ']' at the end of the line of values.

Comment: seems it might be better to change my save format than. And change it so I save my file as a json instead.

Comment: That would probably be the best idea. XML is another popular format, but I like json. It's very simple, and it works well. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html